# Area of triangle formed by circumcircle of triangle an altitude of opposite vertex

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider triangle ABC with AB=3, AC=5, BC=7, where the altitude of A intersects the circumcircle of triangle ABC at X, which is different from A. What would be the area of triangle XBC?

I don't think coordinates would be a good idea, but I honestly do not have any clue to start? Perhaps I am unfamiliar with a geometry theorem needed for this question?

Thanks for any advice you may have!

Comment: I haven't solved this, but if I was to trying to, I would do it by first noting & using some of the properties of $ABCX$ being a [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints-(1). Apply cosine law twice to find $\angle ABC$ and aslo $\angle ACB$.

(2). Let AX cut BC at P. (From $\triangle ABP$) find PB and (from $\triangle APC$) find PC.

(3). Since ABXC is cyclic, $\angle ABC = \angle PXC$.

(4). Find XP.

Required result can then be found.

Comment: I understand your answer, but I am unsure how to find PB, PC, and XP. Could you please elaborate on that? Also I'm not sure why we would need to divide BC into PB and PC if we could just find XP and then use the formula 1/2abcsinC for the area?

Comment: @nak17 See added info in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $|AB|=3=c,\ |AC|=5=b,\ |BC|=7=a$.

Area of $\triangle ABC$  is

\begin{align}
S_{ABC}&=\tfrac14\,\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}
=\tfrac{15}4\,\sqrt3
,\\
|AH|&=\frac{2S_{ABC}}a
=\tfrac{15}{14}\,\sqrt3
,\\
|BH|&=
\sqrt{c^2-|AH|^2}
=\tfrac{33}{14}
,\\
|CH|&=|BC|-|BH|=
=\tfrac{65}{14}
.
\end{align}

By the power of the point $H$ wrt the circumcircle,
\begin{align} 
|BH|\cdot|CH|
&=|AH|\cdot|HX|
,\\
|HX|
&=
\frac{|BH|\cdot|CH|}{|AH|}
=
\tfrac{143}{42}\,\sqrt3
.
\end{align}

$|HX|$ is the altitude of $\triangle XBC$,

so the answer is
\begin{align}
S_{XBC}&=\tfrac12\,|BC|\cdot|HX|
=\tfrac{143}{12}\,\sqrt3
.
\end{align}

Comment: This is the answer I got but in a different way. Thank you, though, for confirmation and another method of solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In general,

$${K_{XBC}}
= K_{ABC}\cot B\cot C$$

which leads to

$$K_{XBC}=\frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2+c^2-b^2)}
{4\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)}}$$

where $a,\>b$ and $c$ are the side lengths of the triangle ABC.